# Putting an audio file in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I work with a radio station and I created its website with Wordpress. The objective is to make visitors listen to the radio from the website.
I received an address I have to put on the website: http://X.X.X.X:8000/stream.mp3
I wanted to put thiss address on an audio widget or via HTML, but it doesn't work. When we download the audio file from the front page, another page is opened and we can listen the live audio.

My objective is to make people listen on the radio from the website.
What must I do ?

I tried to do as if it was a podcast, but the result is the same and there's no sound.
Same with audio plugins.

Comment: Did you try this [Radio Player](https://wordpress.org/plugins/radio-player/) plugin?

Comment: I'm trying this plugin. The website uses https:// and the stream is using http://. I'm contacting the compagny about the plugin. I could consider to use the PRO version. Thanks for your supposition.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.